# How to split the function to two differnt file nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I am new to Node js so please ignore if i am wrong.

I have a file like

```
  exports.Client = function() {
            this.example = function(name, callback) {
                console.log(name);
            };
            this.example1 = function(name1, callback) {
                console.log(name1);
            };

    };
```

I accesss like this

```
var Client = require('./client.js').Client;
var client = new Client();
client.example1=.....
```

How can i split the example1 function to another js file and still use the Client object to access it.

Comment: Your `Client` constructor doesn't make much sense. The instances don't store any information, and the methods do only use their parameter values. Why aren't you putting them on the prototype? Or make `client` a singleton right away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to read this page: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Your javascript module should export the function thanks to `module.exports`.

Content of the example1.js file:

```
module.exports.example1 = function(name1, callback) {
            console.log(name1);
        };
```

You can access to the function thanks to the require function in your `client.js` file:

```
var example1 = require('./example1.js').example1 ;

module.exports.Client = function() {
        this.example = function(name, callback) {
            console.log(name);
        };
        this.example1 = example1;

};
```

Beware, the nodejs modules are singletons.

Answer (score 0):

First, here’s an example:

**client/index.js:**

```
function Client (name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Client.prototype.example = require('./example');

exports.Client = Client;
```

**client/example.js:**

```
module.exports = function () {
  console.log(this.name);
};
```

This is a little different from your original class because it uses `prototype` to add instance methods. But I think you’ll find this will be easier to work with because it gives you access to `this` inside `example.js`.

Also notice you can assign any object to `module.exports` and that’s what you’ll get back from `require`. You don’t have to just add properties to `exports`.